# How to implement Mapbox GL JS with a custom Gutenberg block in FSE?

Tags: block-editor, react

I'm working on a custom Gutenberg block that uses the [Mapbox GL JS](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/) API for displaying a map. To create the map I have to call the following constructor.

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container ID
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12', // style URL
  center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
  zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
```

[According to the documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/), the `container` property can be either a string with the ID of the container or an instance of an `HTMLElement`. Since my implementation is a Gutenberg block, I went with the latter by using `useRef` from the `@wordpress/element` package to reference the container element.

The following code is my implementation:

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from '@wordpress/element';

mapboxgl.accessToken = '*myaccesstoken*';

const Edit = ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {
  const blockProps = useBlockProps();

  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(-70.9);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(42.35);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current !== null || mapContainer.current === null) {
      return;
    }

    mapRef.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: 9
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div {...blockProps}>
      <div id="map" ref={mapContainer}></div>;
    </div>
  )
};

export default Edit;
```

Whenever I use this block in the **Full Site Editing** (FSE) mode, the `mapboxgl.Map` constructor throws the following error:

```
Error: Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement.
```

(This doesn't happen whenever the block is used on a single post).

When logging `mapContainer.current` I can see the `<div #map>` element being logged, though the constructor is not accepting it. **Is the element referenced in `useRef` somehow not an *actual* `HTMLElement` instance?**

I based my implementation on [this Mapbox + React tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/) from their own site.

Selecting a random element outside the block with the DOM API does work as expected. For example `container: document.getElementById('some-id')`. This does indicate that the API works.

Selecting the `<div #map>` from within the `useEffect` hook with the DOM API results in the element not being found.

```
container: 'map' // -> Error: Container 'map' not found
```

```
container: document.getElementById('map') // -> Error: Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement
```

[[image: Github Logo] Github repo of block](https://github.com/EmielZuurbier/wp-mapbox-block)

Comment: I've never used Mapbox GL JS, but I don't think refs are needed. Just use `<div id="map"></div>`, and then the map should initialize correctly by simply passing the container's `id` - `useEffect( () => { const map = new mapboxgl.Map( { container: 'map' } ); ... }, [] )`, or the container's element - just replace the `'map'` with `document.getElementById( 'map' )`. Have you already tried any of that?

Comment: I have indeed tried that. Both `container: 'map'` and `container: document.getElementById('map')` fail to find the element. The former throws the error `Error: Container 'map' not found` and the latter show the error mentioned in the question. I've also turned to the [react-map-gl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-map-gl) package (a React wrapper for the Mapbox GL JS API) but that too threw the same error as in the question.

Comment: In that case, then could you please share your full source code, e.g. a link to your block's GitHub repo?

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for looking into it. I've added a link to the repo to the question.

Comment: Well, I built your block and tried it on a WordPress v6.2.2 site, and your [code](https://github.com/EmielZuurbier/wp-mapbox-block/blob/0280d6d9723dc137249fe45e01673af8c777be67/src/Edit.jsx) worked just fine for me - no errors in the console. However, you should remove the lines 1 (`import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';`) and 52 (`mapLib={mapboxgl}`) - I've already tried removing them and your block still worked fine. [see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoTgS.png)

Comment: Hmmm, I see! Seeing from your screenshot you've added the block to a post. I've tried that as well and the block works there without a hiccup. However, I failed to mention in the question that my behavior occurs in Full Site Editing mode when editing, for example, [my front page template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNayz.jpg). Are you able to replicate this behavior in the FSE mode as well? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Yes, I was able to replicate it, and I've posted an answer explaining the issues/errors. I hope that and [my gist](https://gist.github.com/5ally/fc5c5e6114aa3e2d0337371daa82f9c7) helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [very helpful answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/417667/173559) of [@sally-cj](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj) we found out that Mapbox requires the container property to be an instance of `window.HTMLElement` or a valid `string` to query for an element. Because of the structure of the FSE environment, some browsers, like Firefox<sup>117.0b5</sup>, will not evaluate `instanceof window.HTMLElement` to `true`. This will result in the map throwing the following error.

```
Error: Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement.
```

As a solution we can wrap the creation of `mapboxgl.Map` in a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) with a [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM). This way we can reference the container element from within the custom element, and because the element is in the shadow DOM, it will always be an instance of `window.HTMLElement`.

A implementation of a custom element would look like the snippet below.

### custom-element.js

This snippet will register the custom element as a `mapbox-map` HTML element. The `mapboxgl.Map` will run in the [`connectedCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks). It will fire a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) when the map loads which enables us to listen outside of the custom element for the load event.

```js
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

class MapboxElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.innerHTML = `
      <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.15.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

      <style>
        :host {
          contain: layout;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
        }

        #container {
          display: block;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>

      <div id="container"></div>
    `;
  }

  get container() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#container');
  }

  get accessToken() {
    return this.getAttribute('access-token');
  }

  set accessToken(value) {
    if ('string' === typeof value) {
      this.setAttribute('access-token', value);
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute('access-token');
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      accessToken: this.accessToken,
      container: this.container
    });

    map.on('load', () => {
      const mapReadyEvent = new CustomEvent('mapready', {
        bubbles: true,
        detail: {
          map
        }
      });

      this.dispatchEvent(mapReadyEvent);
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('mapbox-map', MapboxElement);
```

### Edit.js

Here we render the `mapbox-map` element whenever the `accessToken` value isn't empty. It then adds an event listener to the custom element to set the `isLoaded` state whenever the map has been loaded.

The event will also expose the `mapboxgl.Map` instance in the `detail` property of the `CustomEvent`.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from '@wordpress/element';

const Edit = ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {
  const { accessToken } = attributes;
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const blockProps = useBlockProps();
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!accessToken) {
      return;
    }

    setIsLoaded(false);

    mapRef.current.addEventListener('mapready', (event) => {
      const map = event.detail.map;
      // ... Use the map here.

      setIsLoaded(true);
    });
  }, [accessToken]);

  return (
    <div {...blockProps}>
      {accessToken && (
        <mapbox-map
          ref={mapRef}
          access-token={accessToken}
        ></mapbox-map>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### block.json

To load the custom element into both the FSE and frontend, add the [`script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#script) property and reference the `custom-element.js` file.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
  "apiVersion": 3,
  "name": "domain/mapbox-map",
  "title": "Mapbox Map",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
  "script": "file:./custom-element.js",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Is the element referenced in `useRef` somehow not an actual `HTMLElement` instance?**

No, it is.

But (as you've already known it), [Mapbox GL JS <sup>(v2.15.0)</sup> requires that the container, when supplied as an element, be an instance of `window.HTMLElement`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/v2.15.0/src/ui/map.js#L534-L538). ( note the `window.` which means the *parent window* )

And the thing is, on the FSE/Site editor page, the block's editor script which initializes the Mapbox map is in the parent window, but then `div#map` is inside a *child window* which is an `iframe` named `editor-canvas`, hence:

1. `document.getElementById('map')`, where `document` refers to `window.document`, returned a `null`.
2. The map div is *no longer an instance of `window.HTMLElement`* and instead, it's now an instance of the iframe's `contentWindow.HTMLElement`. I.e.

   - `mapContainer.current instanceof HTMLElement` (which is the same as `mapContainer.current instanceof window.HTMLElement`) returns `false`.
   - `mapContainer.current instanceof document.querySelector( 'iframe[name="editor-canvas"]' ).contentWindow.HTMLElement` returns `true`.

*So for the time being, as you commented, you would need to use SSR (i.e. server-side rendering) instead.*

I've created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/5ally/block-map-ssr) with a working example where my `edit` function returns an element with an iframe which renders the Mapbox map, as you could see below: (I used Firefox)

[image: Preview image]

And here's my edit function: ( **see full code [here](https://github.com/5ally/block-map-ssr/blob/trunk/src/edit.js)** )

```js
const Edit = ( { attributes, setAttributes } ) => {
    const { accessToken } = attributes;

    const mapContainer = useRef( null );

    const [ mapLoaded, setMapLoaded ] = useState( false );

    const onMapFrameLoad = () => {
        let map;

        // Note: getMap is defined on the SSR page. It's a custom function which
        // returns the Mapbox instance for the map initialized on that SSR page.
        try {
            map = mapContainer.current.contentWindow.getMap();
        } catch ( error ) {
            console.log( 'Error accessing the Mapbox\'s map instance!', error );
            return;
        }

        map.on( 'load', () => {
            setMapLoaded( true );
            console.log( 'map ready', map );
        } );
    };

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            { /* In this demo, I'm deliberately not using <InspectorControls>. */ }
            <fieldset>
                <TextControl
                    label="Access Token"
                    value={ accessToken }
                    onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { accessToken: value } ) }
                />
            </fieldset>

            { ( accessToken && ! mapLoaded ) && <i>Loading map..</i> }

            { accessToken && (
                <iframe
                    src={ ssrPageUrl( accessToken, 300 ) }
                    width="100%"
                    height="300"
                    style={ { border: 0, overflow: 'hidden' } }
                    id="map-frame"
                    onLoad={ onMapFrameLoad }
                    ref={ mapContainer }
                ></iframe>
            ) }
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Unfortunately the issue persists. I ran your code, as is in the Gist, but it had the the same behavior as my initial attempt. It seems that because the code is running in an `iframe`, the container can never evaluate `instanceof window.HTMLElement` to `true` because the element lives in a different `window`. And this is [exactly what the library is evaluating](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/src/ui/map.js#L535) and is what is causing the error. The only possible solution I can think of is SSR and injecting a JS file with the Mapbox lib.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and already mentioned it in my answer. I'm not sure why are you still getting the same issue, but see [this video](https://www.veed.io/view/22c1c2e4-3be7-4212-a4d8-fa30912f34a1?panel=share) and you can download the plugin [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2p9fsc0vpmoketg/wp-mapbox-block.2.zip?dl=0) - just deactivate your own "Map block" plugin and install my version.

Comment: You did indeed, I was following up on that discovery and didn't word that properly. I must say kudos on all the effort with the epic video. Okay, I think the issue is browser related. I noticed you're using Chrome, while I was using Firefox Dev Edition. FF still gives the error, while Chrome works fine with both our plugins. I guess FF has a different implementation of creating or evaluating instances of `HTMLElement`.

Comment: Well, I've been so much used to using Chrome that I forgot Firefox existed...  And thank you for the kudos, I actually enjoyed creating that video :) So yes, you're right that the snippet did not work on Firefox - the `mapContainer.current.appendChild( mapDiv )` changed the `mapDiv` to being an instance of the iframe's `contentWindow.HTMLElement` - :( ( it worked on Edge and Opera, desktop versions, so I'm not sure which browsers were to blame ‍♀️ ) Anyway, I've completely revised my answer, so I hoped that also helped you.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time with me. I might try to report it as a bug at Mozilla and hope to at least get an explainer as to why this is implemented differently than other vendors.

Comment: I've made progress and wanted to share it with you. The solution is not to use SSR but Web Components and Shadow DOM. When the map container is within a Shadow DOM of a custom element, then the reference to the container element can always be found and will be a instance of `window.HTMLElement` regardless of the custom element being in an `iframe` or not.

Comment: I did think about something like `class MapDiv extends HTMLElement`, but did not dig deeper at [using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements), and thanks for sharing about [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM)  which obviously I never used.. So maybe you should post your solution as an answer and accept it later - after unaccepting my answer 